# Recaptcha. Need some php script for integrating recaptcha to existing form. This may be a simple answer

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am not that experienced at html and php but I managed to create a contact form and php script for sending emails to my hotmail account and it has been working fine.

Now i wanted to add Recaptcha to that form and I did it successfully. But now I would like some help on the next topics:

- I want to make recpatcha work with my form
- when recaptcha is Incorrect I want to keep the information fields  and Not send the email also Not show the "thank you your message has been sent".
- only when recaptcha is Correct: send the email, clear the information fields, show "thank you message has been sent"

SORRY i FORGOT TO MENTION THIS SCRIPT IS ALL IN ONE PAGE CALL "CONTACTFORM.PHP"
And by the way, this is a She.

Thank you very much for your answers! If you can give some details for the answer would be great!!!

here I have my codes:

Any help will be very appreciate!

This is my php for sending my email:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "form1"){

    $emailTitle = 'Email from my website!';
    $emailAddress = 'myemail@hotmail.com';

    /* Gathering Data Variables */

    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $subjectField = $_POST['subject'];
    $messageField = $_POST['message'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $emailField <br />
Phone: $phoneField <br />
Name: $nameField <br />
Subject: $subjectField <br />
Message: $messageField <br />
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail("$emailAddress", "$emailTitle", "$body", "$headers");

    $sent = "Thank you! Your message has been sent."; 
}
?> 

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="contactform.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="email" class="titulos">Email: </label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35" maxlength="50" /> 
            *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="phone" class="titulos">Phone: </label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="35" maxlength="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="name" class="titulos">Name:</label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="35" maxlength="30" />
            *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="subject" class="titulos">Subject:</label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="35" maxlength="60" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="top"><label for="message" class="titulos">Message:</label></td>
          <td align="left"><p>
            <textarea name="message" cols="27" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
            *</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

   if (!$resp->is_valid) {
      echo "Please try again";
   } else {
      echo "Correct"; 
   }
}
?>
<?php
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // you got this from the signup page
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td align="right"><label for="reset"></label></td>
          <td align="left"><label for="send"></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="parse_var" id="parse_var" value="form1" />

            <input name="send" type="submit" id="send" onclick="MM_validateForm('email','','RisEmail','name','','R','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Send Email" /> <label for="reset"></label>
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset form" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" class="content">(*) Are Required fields</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php print "$sent"; ?> 



         </td>
          </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all learn [PHP SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Here your algorithm :

1. SHow your form with recaptcha (form.php)
2. Send your form to step2.php for checking recaptcha , if it's right, send email. If it's wrong, set email, phone, name, subject and message to a session (for example : `$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];`) (you have to start session with `session_start();` , at top of step2.php) and redirect to your form page with a querystring. like this : `form.php?error=r`
3. CHeck `r` querystring at form.php. If there is, print an error
   `Wrong Rechaptcha` and set all `<input>`'s default values to
   `$_SESSION` values. (`$_SESSION["name"]`)

**IF YOU WANT TO DO IT WITH ONE PAGE (RECOMMENDED)**

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"])  // If form submitted
{
// recaptcha control. If pass, record it to database, or send mail, or whatever you want.
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" name="name" type="textbox">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use sessions. Check my answer below

Comment: Yes of course it's better way to do this. But he has 2 pages. So, i said this. Shortly, **Tom's answer is best way, for now** :)

Comment: Ok, yeah that's true. if you're going to have 2 pages, then sessions is one way to carry variables. However, I'ld recommend to use only 1 page. You could also use $_GET to carry variables from one page to another

Comment: @Tom, yes it's me :) But, carry form variables with $_GET is really unsecure.

Comment: well, in the case of contact forms it doesn't really matter as you normally validate the inputs on the PHP page right before you send the email

Comment: Hi Eray thank you for your answers, but my contact form is all in one page called contactformphp.

Comment: maybe that changes the answer you gave me before, if could please send me some details to add to my conatact form.

Comment: @user1162681 , so you can copy step2.php's content to form.php :) Just look at Tom's answer :)